# CXF, Blueprint, OSGI: Securing my web services

Tags: web-services, rest, cxf, blueprint

Excuse me for this very noobish question.

I currently have a few RESTful/SOAP web services running on CXF. (Three of them actually) Here's a sample

```
<blueprint ...>
 <reference id="myWebServiceRef"
  interface="com.keeboi.samples.MyWebService" />
 <jaxrs:server address="/my-web-service" id="myWebService">
  <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
   <ref component-id="myWebServiceImpl" />
  </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
 </jaxrs:server>
 <bean id="myWebServiceImpl"
  class="com.keeboi.samples.MyWebServiceImpl">
  <property name="myWebService" ref="myWebServiceRef" />
 </bean>
</blueprint>
```

And I access them via ajax calls

```
$.ajax({
    url : ws_url + id,
    type : "GET",
    dataType : 'text',
}).done(function(data) {
    // Magic happens
});
```

What I'd like is for these web services to be inaccessible to requests done by users as they are used internally. How do I secure these web services?

Adding:

```
<jaxrs:properties>
  <entry key="org.apache.cxf.endpoint.private" value="true" />
</jaxrs:properties>
```

Makes them private but inaccessible to my ajax requests... I'm obviously missing something here. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the ajax part. But try to answer the cxf security part

In blueprint configuration add below configuration:

```
 <httpj:engine-factory bus="cxf">
 <httpj:engine port="9081">
<httpj:tlsServerParameters>
  <sec:keyManagers keyPassword="skpass">
       <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="sspass"
             resource="keystore/serviceKeystore.jks"/>
  </sec:keyManagers>
  <sec:trustManagers>
      <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="sspass"
            resource="keystore/serviceKeystore.jks"/>
  </sec:trustManagers>
  <sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
    <sec:include>.*_EXPORT_.*</sec:include>
    <sec:include>.*_EXPORT1024_.*</sec:include>
    <sec:include>.*_WITH_DES_.*</sec:include>
    <sec:include>.*_WITH_AES_.*</sec:include>
    <sec:include>.*_WITH_NULL_.*</sec:include>
    <sec:exclude>.*_DH_anon_.*</sec:exclude>
  </sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
  <sec:clientAuthentication want="false" required="false"/>
</httpj:tlsServerParameters>
```

You can refer [Configuring SSL] for more info[1](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/standalone-http-transport.html)